# Trigger for a water sensor

Tags: motor, relay, circuit-design, circuit-protection, water

I want to build a water sensor that disconnects the motor when:
1. tank is full
2. water in input pipe is missing.

I came up with the following schematics (haven't practiced much electronics in last 10 years :))

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIpkIU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Sensors**
The sensors are just 2 wires (R1, R2).

- R1 (priming water sensor) is the resistance of input water (let's say [2K when water present](https://www.google.de/search?q=tap%20water%20resistance) and 1M when water missing). This makes sure the motor is not running without water.
- R2 (tank full sensor) is the resistance of second water sensor.

Seems to work but I see a residual current (few mA) in the relay. The relay makes contact at 15mA, but I think firm contact is at 25mA.

I need to know if the relay might oscillate. Do I need some kind of digital trigger to make sure the relay is either on or off, but not in the middle?

Comment: You need to fix the link to your schematic.

Answer (score 1):

Simple and straightforward would be using float switches. A float switch has a metal ball inside that pushes a micro switch. With regard to the inclination of float switch the contact changes to on/off. Almost every pump is equipped with such float switch for preventing dry running.

Comment: Thanks. I could install a float switch in the water tank but not on the input pipe. Or?

Comment: wow - those switches are around 10 euros on Amazon.de!

Answer (score 0):

You may be better to use a cheap comparator like an LM339 with some hysteresis on it. Otherwise this is going to turn on and off rather a lot. You also don't really need a relay, a MOSFET driver would be better.

Perhaps something like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f30atz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note I added a small delay filter R19 and C1 which you may need if the signal from the tank-full sensor is erratic while the pump runs.

Comment: Thanks, but that is too complex for me to design :). But the FET idea is great. I want to build the circuit with whatever parts I have home and I disabled some TVs and a computer. There must be some FETs there :)

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted? It is a very good answer.

Comment: @BorlImpriceGoGearEmbaIdera who knows....